# my Rest controller in spring boot app 3 send embedded Object as Number and sometimes as Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, spring-restcontroller

I am working with spring boot 3, I have an entity called UniteEnseignement that looks like this :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "UNITE_ENSEIGNEMENT")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class UniteEnseignement implements Identifiable<UniteEnseignementId>{
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "codeFormation est Requis!")
    @EmbeddedId
    private UniteEnseignementId id;


    @NotNull(message = "noEnseignant est Requis!")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENSEIGNANT", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    private Enseignant noEnseignant; }
```

UniteEnseignementId :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UniteEnseignementId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8208650618508750641L;
    @Column(name = "CODE_FORMATION", nullable = false, length = 8)
    @NotBlank(message = "codeFormation est Requis!")
    private String codeFormation;

    @Column(name = "CODE_UE", nullable = false, length = 8)
    @NotBlank(message = "codeUe est Requis!")
    private String codeUe;
}
```

Entity Enseignant :

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENSEIGNANT")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Enseignant  implements  Identifiable<Long>{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NO_ENSEIGNANT", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ens_seq", sequenceName = "ens_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ens_seq")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "noEnseignant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    @JsonBackReference(value="noEnseignant")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UniteEnseignement> listUE;
}
```

I want to call my Controller : UEController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/unites_enseignement")
public class UEController extends BaseController<UniteEnseignement, UniteEnseignementId> {

    @Autowired
    public UEController(UEService ueService) {
        super(ueService);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UniteEnseignement> getAll() {
        for( UniteEnseignement ue : super.getAll())
            System.out.println(ue.getNoEnseignant());
        return super.getAll();
    }
}
```

in my console it prints it correctly :

```
[UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=ISI)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=1, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='S', prenom='P'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Ingénierie des Systèmes d'Information', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=30, nbhTd=30, nbhTp=30}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=IDL)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=1, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='S', prenom='P'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Ingénierie de Développement Logiciel', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=20, nbhTd=20, nbhTp=20}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=J2EE)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=2, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='LL', prenom='MM'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Java/J2EE', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=20, nbhTd=20, nbhTp=20}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=SR)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=2, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='LL', prenom='MM'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Systèmes Répartis', semestre='10 ', description='null', nbhCm=20, nbhTd=20, nbhTp=20}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=EDE)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=3, type='PRAST', sexe='H', nom='Jean', prenom='Patrick'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Environnement de Développement', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=0, nbhTd=0, nbhTp=48}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=WEB)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=3, type='PRAST', sexe='H', nom='Jean', prenom='Patrick'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Langages du WEB', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=20, nbhTd=20, nbhTp=20}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=CO)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=5, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='KER', prenom='Pat'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Conception Objet', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=20, nbhTd=20, nbhTp=20}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=PCO)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=1, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='S', prenom='P'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Préparation au Contexte de l'Offshore', semestre='10 ', description='null', nbhCm=16, nbhTd=16, nbhTp=16}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=MMM)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=1, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='S', prenom='P'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Ingénierie des Systèmes d'Information', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=20, nbhTd=20, nbhTp=20}, UniteEnseignement{id=UniteEnseignementId(codeFormation=M2DOSI, codeUe=DIDI)noEnseignantEnseignant{id=1, type='MCF', sexe='H', nom='S', prenom='P'}, codeFormation=Formation{id='M2DOSI', diplome='M', n0Annee=3, nomFormation='Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information', doubleDiplome='O', debutAccreditation=2012-09-01, finAccreditation=2017-09-30}, designation='Ingénierie des Systèmes d'Information', semestre='9  ', description='null', nbhCm=30, nbhTd=30, nbhTp=30}]
```

but in my postman, sometimes it gives me Object sometimes as Long.

```
[
    {
        "id": {
            "codeFormation": "M2DOSI",
            "codeUe": "ISI"
        },
        "codeFormation": {
            "id": "M2DOSI",
            "diplome": "M",
            "n0Annee": 3,
            "nomFormation": "Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information",
            "doubleDiplome": "O",
            "debutAccreditation": "01-09-2012",
            "finAccreditation": "30-09-2017",
            "debutAccreditationBeforeFinAccreditation": true
        },
        "noEnseignant": {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "MCF",
            "sexe": "H",
            "nom": "S",
            "prenom": "P",
            "adresse": "6 rue de l'eglise",
            "codePostal": "29860",
            "ville": "LE DRENNEC",
            "pays": "FR",
            "mobile": "06.00.00.01.00",
            "telephone": "02.98.01.69.74",
            "emailUbo": "ps@univ-brest.fr",
            "emailPerso": "ps@gmail.com"
        },
        "designation": "Ingénierie des Systèmes d'Information",
        "semestre": "9  ",
        "description": null,
        "nbhCm": 30,
        "nbhTd": 30,
        "nbhTp": 30
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "codeFormation": "M2DOSI",
            "codeUe": "IDL"
        },
        "codeFormation": {
            "id": "M2DOSI",
            "diplome": "M",
            "n0Annee": 3,
            "nomFormation": "Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information",
            "doubleDiplome": "O",
            "debutAccreditation": "01-09-2012",
            "finAccreditation": "30-09-2017",
            "debutAccreditationBeforeFinAccreditation": true
        },
        "noEnseignant": 1,
        "designation": "Ingénierie de Développement Logiciel",
        "semestre": "9  ",
        "description": null,
        "nbhCm": 20,
        "nbhTd": 20,
        "nbhTp": 20
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "codeFormation": "M2DOSI",
            "codeUe": "J2EE"
        },
        "codeFormation": {
            "id": "M2DOSI",
            "diplome": "M",
            "n0Annee": 3,
            "nomFormation": "Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information",
            "doubleDiplome": "O",
            "debutAccreditation": "01-09-2012",
            "finAccreditation": "30-09-2017",
            "debutAccreditationBeforeFinAccreditation": true
        },
        "noEnseignant": {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "MCF",
            "sexe": "H",
            "nom": "LL",
            "prenom": "MM",
            "adresse": "18rue du pont",
            "codePostal": "29200",
            "ville": "BREST",
            "pays": "FR",
            "mobile": "06.00.00.00.32",
            "telephone": "02.08.01.67.32",
            "emailUbo": "mm@univ-brest.fr",
            "emailPerso": "mm@gmail.com"
        },
        "designation": "Java/J2EE",
        "semestre": "9  ",
        "description": null,
        "nbhCm": 20,
        "nbhTd": 20,
        "nbhTp": 20
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "codeFormation": "M2DOSI",
            "codeUe": "SR"
        },
        "codeFormation": {
            "id": "M2DOSI",
            "diplome": "M",
            "n0Annee": 3,
            "nomFormation": "Master Développement à l'Offshore des Systèmes d'Information",
            "doubleDiplome": "O",
            "debutAccreditation": "01-09-2012",
            "finAccreditation": "30-09-2017",
            "debutAccreditationBeforeFinAccreditation": true
        },
        "noEnseignant": 2,
        "designation": "Systèmes Répartis",
        "semestre": "10 ",
        "description": null,
        "nbhCm": 20,
        "nbhTd": 20,
        "nbhTp": 20
    }
]
```

I want to send always noEnseignant as Object.

I have try to set noEnseignant in a loop, but I dont think it is a problem of service, because even in my Controller it prints everything right.

Comment: The long value is referring to the id of `Enseignant` class, the behaviour is due to avoid the infinite recursion.

Comment: so what is the solution, do i need to fetch again in my front ? or there is another solution in backend ?

Answer (score 0):

removing this from entity Enseignant solve the problem.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

The `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation with PropertyGenerator as the generator type and "id" as the property name tells Jackson to use object identity when serializing the class. In other words, when Jackson encounters the same object reference multiple times, it will only include the full serialization of that object once, and subsequent references to the same object will be represented as a reference to the original object's ID.